# jquery issue in IE7 and IE8 when i hover over field

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Website is http://www.re-org.co.uk/indexnew.php

If you go to the job search section to the right in this page, there is a feature I am trying to get an image file to appear when you hover over. In IE7 and 8 only it forces the field to drop down.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

  $('#changehover').hide();
  $('#changehoverloc').hide();

    //---- Country Change

    $(".countryhover").mouseover(function(){
        $("#changehover").show();
    });
    $(".countryhover").mouseout(function(){
        $("#changehover").hide();
    });  

    //---- Location Change

    $(".locationhover").mouseover(function(){
        $("#changehoverloc").show();
    });
    $(".locationhover").mouseout(function(){
        $("#changehoverloc").hide();
    });  
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#changehover{
    background:url(../images/change_hover.png) no-repeat top ;
    width:100px;
    height:44px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:right;
}
#changehoverloc{
    background:url(../images/change_hover.png) no-repeat top ;
    width:100px;
    height:44px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:right;
}
```

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work fine for me in IE7 and IE8. Are you talking about the **Click to change** image that appears when hovering over the fields?